# Как сделать HorizontalPager с разными экранами?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Нашел аналог ViewPager2 в Jetpack Сompose — `HorizontalPager`. Не могу понять, как реализовать его с тремя разными экранами. Каждый экран имеет разную верстку.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: С чем конкретно у вас возникли сложности? Приведите код, что вы сделали, и что именно не удалось сделать? Добавьте код в вопрос, нажав на кнопку [edit] под вопросом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы сделать [`HorizontalPager`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/pager) с тремя разными экранами, вызывайте разные Composable-функции в зависимости от номера страницы `index`.

Это можно сделать с помощью выражения [`when`](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/control-flow.html):

```kotlin
HorizontalPager(pageCount = 3) { index ->
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), Alignment.Center) {
        when (index) {
            0 -> MyScreen1()
            1 -> MyScreen2()
            2 -> MyScreen3()
        }
    }
}
```